# CREATE EVENT; erro de sintaxe somente dentro do mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando executar um comando de evento no `mysql`, ao desenvolver a query no *mysql workbench*, funcionou normalmente, porém quando uso dentro do *mysqli_query do php* é exibido o seguinte erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'delimiter | CREATE EVENT evento1 ON SCHE' at line 1

segue abaixo o código:

```
$sql = $conexao->query("delimiter |
                        CREATE EVENT evento1
                        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
                        STARTS TIMESTAMP '2016-08-17 15:00:00'
                        DO
                          BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO cliente_atendimento_cabecalho       (atecabec_id, atecabec_total_atendimento, atecabec_prioridade, atecabec_agendamento, atecabec_data_abertura, atecabec_data_encerrado, atecabec_cod_tipo_atendimento, atecabec_cod_operador, atecabec_cod_cliente)
                            VALUES ( '$protocolo', '$total_atendimento', '$prioridade', '$agendamento', '$data_abertura_fechamento', '$encerrado', '$cod_tipo_atendimento', '$cod_operador', '$cod_cliente');

                            INSERT INTO cliente_atendimento_corpo (atecorp_descricao_solicitada, atecorp_data_abertura, atecorp_cod_departamento, atecorp_cod_operador, atecorp_cod_cabecalho)
                            VALUES ('$msg', '$data_abertura_fechamento', '$cod_departamento', '$cod_operador', '$protocolo');
                        END |
                       delimiter ;");
```

Comment: Cara porque você esta criando um evento no php?ainda mais com parâmetros para insert? o CREATE EVENT é uma funcionalidade que é executado automaticamente pelo banco.

Comment: Preciso fazer com que o usuario possa cadastrar um tipo de  atendimento agendado mensal, que a cada mês automaticamente seja gerado um protocolo de atendimento para o cliente

Comment: Então você vai ter que criar algum tipo de evento do próprio PHP ou um que monte seu insert e depois execute a query no banco. a não ser que você tenha esses dados salvo no banco de dados, ai bastava alterá os paramentos para um select.

Comment: Porque não pode ser feito assim? antes estava com uma query de evento simples apenas com um insert e estava funcionando normalmente, depois que eu modifiquei pra funcionar com as duas que começou a dar erro :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri, o problema está nos "delimiters", ao que parece, não é necessário colocá-los dentro do mysqli_query(). O código ficou assim:

```
    $sql = $conexao->query("CREATE EVENT evento1
                            ON SCHEDULE
                            EVERY 1 DAY
                            STARTS TIMESTAMP '2016-08-17 15:00:00'
                            DO
                            BEGIN
                                INSERT INTO cliente_atendimento_cabecalho (atecabec_id, atecabec_total_atendimento, atecabec_prioridade, atecabec_agendamento, atecabec_data_abertura, atecabec_data_encerrado, atecabec_cod_tipo_atendimento, atecabec_cod_operador, atecabec_cod_cliente)
                                VALUES ( '".$protocolo."', '".$total_atendimento."', '".$prioridade."', '".$agendamento."', '".$data_abertura_fechamento."', '".$encerrado."', '".$cod_tipo_atendimento."', '".$cod_operador."', '".$cod_cliente."');
                                INSERT INTO cliente_atendimento_corpo (atecorp_descricao_solicitada, atecorp_data_abertura, atecorp_cod_departamento, atecorp_cod_operador, atecorp_cod_cabecalho)
                                VALUES ('".$msg."', '".$data_abertura_fechamento."', '".$cod_departamento."', '".$cod_operador."', '".$protocolo."');
                            END;");
```